# How to pass vector as function argument to pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, arguments

I try to pass vector as a function argument to pointer but compiler always return error.

> error: cannot convert 'std::vector' to 'float*' in assignment

When I have passed array in the same way it works perfectly. So what is wrong here? Is it possible to assign vector to pointer?

```
vector <float> test;

class data {
    float *pointer;
    int size;
  public:
      void init(vector <float> &test, int number);
};

void data::init(vector <float> &test, int number)
{
    size= number;
    pointer = test;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a pointer to the array managed by the vector, then that's

```
pointer = test.data();                       // C++11 or later
pointer = test.empty() ? NULL : &test[0];    // primeval dialects
```

Beware that this will be invalidated if the vector is destroyed, or reallocates its memory.

Comment: I would say `std::addressof` to manage `operator &` in the old case but it is also C++11 (yes, I know, it is not a problem with `float`)...

Comment: The "primeval" version needs a check for empty.

Comment: @DonReba: Good point. I'm glad I don't live in the past.

Comment: test.data() works and it seems that I don't have problem with reallocation.  But is it possible to say exactly don't destroy this vector before I destroy vector by test.clear()?

Comment: @astrak: Just to be clear, destruction isn't the only potential issue. If the vector grows, that will also invalidate your pointer.

Comment: @FredLarson Yes, I know. But it was a good point. There is always problem with that when I need something like vectors between functions. I tried to solve it by putting vector to the global scope but I think it could be deleted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, you may use `std::vector::data`

```
void data::init(std::vector<float> &test, int number)
{
    size = number;
    pointer = test.data();
}
```